# How to compare to decimal values in if statement?

Tags: shell

I want to compare two decimal values in if statement, but it is not giving as expected.
Suppose,I have one decimal value in $value variable.  Then    `if [ $value -eq 0.00 ]` is not working eventhough `$value` is `0.00`.

Please help in this regard.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Some shells support float, others don't:

- Bash doesn't support float values.
- Zsh does support float values.

In any case, the `-eq` operator exists to perform comparison between integers, not float (even in Zsh).

I don't know which shell you're using, but there is two solutions. Choose the one you prefer: avoid an external dependency or manipulate real floats.

#### Consider floats as strings

This way, you can compare string directly with the `=` operator (the string equality operator).

```
A=1.1
B=1.1
if [ "$A" = "$B" ] ; then
    echo 'Yeah!'
fi
```

#### Use bc to perform real float operations

`bc` is a calculator which can be called (as any other program) in a shell script expression.

```
A=1.1
B=1.1
if [ "$(bc <<< "$A - $B")" = 0 ] ; then
    echo 'Yeah!'
fi
```

Comment: like the first method.

Comment: Actually I am using Bash shell, I have used first method and got the correct output..Thank you very much..:)